# Selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I loop through multiple URLs searching for a class and click it, but when the class is not clickable in some pages the loop gets broken, what is the best way to ignore the current bad URL and continue with the loop

**Error**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: 
Element <span class="icon inlblk vtop b_phone4"></span> is not clickable
```

**code**

```
def single_page():
titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='ads__item__ad--title']")
with open('posts.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        driver.get(line)
        phone = driver.find_element_by_class_name("b_phone4")
        time.sleep(1)
        phone.click()
        print("phone clicked")
        time.sleep(1)
        phone_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contact_methods"]/li/div/strong')
        # time.sleep(1)
        print(phone_value.text)
```

I have tried the code below but didn't work

```
if phone:
        phone.click()
        print("phone clicked")
        time.sleep(1)
        phone_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contact_methods"]/li/div/strong')
        # time.sleep(1)
        print(phone_value.text)
    else:
        f += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `try` inside your loop,you have to add continue inside the except as following:

```
    for line in f:
       try:
        driver.get(line)
        phone = driver.find_element_by_class_name("b_phone4")
        time.sleep(1)
        phone.click()
        print("phone clicked")
        time.sleep(1)
        phone_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contact_methods"]/li/div/strong')
        # time.sleep(1)
        print(phone_value.text)
      except Exception as error:
        continue
```

Comment: thanks @Rola it works, would please share why it works and the if condition didn't work?

Comment: @IhabHamed `try` will catch any exception any where within `try` block. So, it's more reliable to ensure looping over all items. `if` statement will only handle missing `phone`. Yet if you prefer using `if` statement, replace `f += 1` with `continue` under `else` ...  you don't need `f += 1`